# Actionscript how to stop one sound from button click

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I stop a certain sound in animated CC. I already have a button that starts the movie but when I click on the button I want the intro sound to stop and the new sound to start. If I click the button before I've finished the intro tho sounds are playing on top of each other. Below is the code for my start button:

`import flash.events.MouseEvent;`
`knapp_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,starta);`
`function starta(event:MouseEvent):void`
`{`

`play();`

`}`

`stop();`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put sound on frame not get called by code.

If so you may select the wave shape on the timeline and select `Stream` option from the menu (the `Properties` tab) (on the right on default/`Essentials`).

By that you can control the sound wave like stopping and starting and so on.

Edit:
Here is a picture what I am talking about.

[image]